# ハッシュ値の取得について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, d

Ruby初心者です．
ある値や文字列を与えたときにそのハッシュ値を取得するメソッドは標準ライブラリでありますでしょうか．
他言語で言えば，D言語の場合，hashOf関数があります．

```
// D lang
hash_value = cast(uint)hashOf(num)
```

自分で値を定めるのではなく，何かしらの値を引数として与えたらそのハッシュ値のみがほしいです．
ご教授宜しくお願いします．

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.hash`というまんまのメソッドがあります。
Rubyは文字列も、数字もオブジェクトなので、そのまま使えます。

```
irb(main):001:0> "abcde".hash
=> 4413543108481966920
irb(main):002:0> 12345.hash
=> 1889650806313118601
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます．実際に実装してみまして，気になることが有りました．この.hashメソッドの実行結果（Hash値）は実行毎に変わりますでしょうか．

Comment: `.hash`の値は連想配列のキーになる値なので、同じ値に対しては同じhash値が返ってくることが保証されます。ただし、自作クラスに`.hash`を行うと、オブジェクトのアドレスをベースに`.hash`を計算するので、同じ内容のオブジェクトでも、それぞれが別に`.new`されたオブジェクトだと異なるhash値が帰ってくることがありますので、その場合は`.hash`をオーバーライドして、メンバーの値を元におなじhash値を返す`.hash`を実装する必要が出てくることがあります

Comment: ご丁寧にありがとうございます．`.new` のオブジェクト毎に変化することはわかりました．現在，以下のような実装でUnitTestしているのですが，このときHash値が変わってしまいます．Hash値が変化しないようにするためにはどうしたら良いでしょうか．
大変見づらく，申し訳ありません．  

`# ハッシュ値を取得するテストコード  

require 'test/unit'  


# 引数のハッシュ値に基づく乱数生成器を設定する
def uniqueRandom(*args)

 sumHash = 0
 p sumHash
 p args
 args.each{ |i|
  p i.to_s + "のHash値" + i.hash.to_s
  sumHash = sumHash + i.hash
 }
 rnd = Random.new(sumHash)

 return rnd
end

class UnitTest < Test::Unit::TestCase

 def test_getHashValue

  uniqueRandom(10, "Channel")

 end

end`

Comment: 外出しており、回答出来ず申し訳ありません。質問に対する直接のコメントで解決した場合は、その結果をご自身で回答に投稿し、承認してくださると、解決済みの問題として参照してくれる人が増えると思いますし、スコアも増えますので、お手数ですが協力いただけると、よりこのコミュニティが使える物になっていくと思います